# How to add an exception test for the below Http call that returns a json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mstest

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("TnC")]
public IHttpActionResult TnC(CustomViewModel myViewModel)
{
    try
    {
        return Json(_Internal.TnC(myViewModel, LoggedInUser));
    }
    catch (BusinessException exception)
    {
        return Json(BuildErrorModelBase(exception));
    }
}
```

Where the `_Internal` is a Service with a guaranteed 99.99% up-time and not formalized fault contract interfaces defined.

Exceptions which are handled in my application level(business layer level) as a **`BusinessException`** - root class

Where **BusinessException** is defined as follows

```
public class BusinessException : Exception
{
    BusinessException()...
    BusinessExceptionFoo()...
    BusinessExceptionBar()...
    //...
}
```

And the current test Method is

**To do : Add Exception test**

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(BusinessException),
        "Not a valid Business Case")]
public void TnCTest()
{
    var bookingService = myContainer.Resolve<mySvc>();

    var controller = new LinkBookingController(mySvc, myContainer);
    var expectedResult = controller.TnC(new myViewModel
    {
        ...params
    });

    var actualResult = GetData<Result<myViewModel>>(expectedResult);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```

`expectedResult==actualResult` does not test the exception block of the code. 
How do I construct a request that makes the service throw the exception other than manually removing the ethernet cable to get this specific type of server error.

The best I could come up with was

```
#if DEBUG && UnitTestExceptions
        throw new BusinessException();
#endif
```

But there is gotta be a better option.

Comment: What is `_Internal`? If this is an abstracted dependency then you can create a mock/stub that throws the exception when `TnC` is called. Also your test can expect the exception if you are catching it within the action.

Comment: _Internal does not do anything else but calls a high availability service. which is is highly unlikely that there is an exception(99.99%), we can never unit test the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things of concern with the method under test.

It is mixing cross-cutting concerns in the action that should be refactored out into an `ExceptionHandler`. Chances are that piece of code is repeated many times in that controller and others like it (DRY).

```
public class WebApiExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler {

    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context) {
        var innerException = context.ExceptionContext.Exception;
        // Ignore HTTP errors
        if (innerException.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(System.Web.HttpException))) {
            return;
        }

        if(innerException is BusinessException) {
            context.Result = BuildErrorResult(exception);
            return;
        }

        //...other handler code
    }

    IHttpActionResult BuildErrorResult(BusinessException exception) { 
        //... your logic here 
    }
}
```

The following extension method could be used to add the handler to the `HttpConfiguration` during startup which also assumes that the application is taking advantage of dependency inversion services.

```
public static HttpConfiguration ReplaceExceptionHandler(this HttpConfiguration config) {
    var errorHandler = config.Services.GetExceptionHandler();
    if (!(errorHandler is WebApiExceptionHandler)) {
        var service = config.Services.GetService(typeof(WebApiExceptionHandler));
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), service);
    }
    return config;
}
```

Now that cross-cutting concerns have been dealt with the action becomes a lot simpler and easier to test. This is a simplified example of an ApiController

```
public class LinkBookingController : ApiController {
    private IBookingService bookingService;

    public LinkBookingController(IBookingService service) {
        bookingService = service;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("TnC")]
    public IHttpActionResult TnC(CustomViewModel myViewModel) {

        return Json(bookingService.TnC(myViewModel, User));

    }
}
```

where `IBookingService` is defined as

```
public interface IBookingService {
    BookingModel TnC(CustomViewModel viewModel, IPrincipal user);
}
```

Using a mocking framework like Moq an exception can be made to be thrown as needed.

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(BusinessException), "Not a valid Business Case")]
public void TnC_Should_Throw_BusinessException() {
    //Arrange
    var bookingService = new Mock<IBookingService>();

    var controller = new LinkBookingController(bookingService.Object);

    var viewModel  = new myViewModel
    {
        //...params
    };

    bookingService.Setup(_ => _.TnC(viewModel, It.IsAny<IPrincipal>())).Throws<BusinessException>()

    //Act
    var expectedResult = controller.TnC(viewModel);

    //Assert
    //...the ExpectedException attribute should assert if it was thrown
}
```

To test how that exception can be handled do a unit test on the exception handler and not the controller as that is not the responsibility of the controller.

Try to keep controllers lean and focused on its UI concerns.

Answer (score 1):

As Nkosi mentioned in his comment, what you need to do is add an interface to whatever type `_Internal` is so that your controller now depends on an interface as a contract, rather than the specific implementation.

Next, create a second constructor for your controller that accepts a IInternalService (whatever its called) and assigns that to `_Internal`. Your parameterless constructor can still assign whatever instance you're using now.

Now that you have this configuration (often called "poor mans dependency injection"), your unit test can create an instance of your controller passing in a different implementation of your service that throws an exception. You can do this by creating a new class, or you can do it dynamically using a library like Moq.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: it makes sense. However the _Internal does nothing but calls a service which is available 99%.  How do I make it throw an exception which It might, but never does

Comment: The new class that you would create and inject in place of your actual service would always throw just the exception. You are trying to test the error handling here not the service itself right?